# Add Computer and User to Domain - Can't login

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, active-directory, group-policy, windows-domain

I have set up a domain on my netowrk, as following:

Domain Controller:
HostName: DC001
OS: WS2008R2 Domain name: test.local
Domain admin user: diego
Domain admin user: password

User "diego" can login successfully to domain controller, and he is member of the following groups:   - Administrators
- Domain Admins
- Domain Users
- Enterprise Admins
- Group Policy Creator
- Schema Admins

I have a Second Server: HostName: PC0002
OS: WS2008R2
User: Administrator
Pwd: Password

I have added it to domain "test.local"

I Expect to be able to logon on PC0002 using the following credentials:
Domain admin user: diego
Domain admin user: password

but I am not able to do it.

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

On the first Login, you need to provide domain name in addition to user name, like test.local\diego. Otherwise the authentification will try PC0002\diego which fails.

Comment: I have tried with:  user: test.local\diego   pwd: password but it says that credentials are not valid

Comment: Tried test\diego or diego@test.local also have you got another machine to test this with on that domain if not you might have to log in to the local user in Pc0002 drop it off the domain and re-add it...

Comment: Try to logon into PC0002 with domain Admin account. If even this fails, you may need to rejoin the PC into the domain as ChalesH describes.

Comment: I have rejoined the PC into domain, and to do that I had to use domain administrator credentials. Anyway the problem still persists